# The code to execute DEL command using cmd.exe is taking forever

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, command-line, process

I want to delete all *.tmp files in a temp folder in my C# application.

The code to execute DEL command using cmd.exe is taking forever. It stays at `Process.WaitForExit()` forever and `Process.HasExited` remains false. But the same command runs well if used manually in cmd:

```
DEL /Q /F "C:\Users\WinUser\AppData\Local\Temp\abc\*.tmp"
```

Code:

```
Process Process = new Process();

Process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
Process.StartInfo.Arguments = " DEL /Q /C /F \"C:\\Users\\WinUser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\abc\\*.tmp\"";
Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Process.Start();

Process.WaitForExit();

while (!Process.HasExited)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error");
}
```

**Note: My mistake was that I was using /C after DEL and the correct command line is:

```
Process.StartInfo.Arguments = " cmd /C DEL /Q /F \"C:\\Users\\WinUser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\abc\\*.tmp\"";
```

Though, I will switch to .NET framework based deletion code mentioned below. But I initially selected command line (cmd.exe) based operation because `Process.WaitForExit()` does not hang program while execution. I have 1000+ files to delete in the delete operation.

Comment: Don't you need /c to execute a command? http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html Did you even test this by using the Run window?

Comment: @ta-speot-is I had used /C but in run cmd, it says invalid switch.

Comment: Why not use the `Directory.GetFiles()` foreach them with `File.Delete()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a /C to the arguments:

```
Process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C DEL /Q /F \"C:\\Users\\WinUser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\abc\\*.tmp\"";
```

Otherwise it will just run cmd.exe and never exit.

Comment: I had used /C but in run cmd, it says invalid switch.

Comment: Try it in a cmd window. "cmd DEL ..." will just start a new cmd session. "cmd /C DEL ..." will run the deletion.

Comment: Thanks. Trying now. Does Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute have any effect?

Comment: When you launch a new cmd the first argument need to be a valid switch in this case "/C", and after that you write the arguments inside, of course "/C" and their arguments both need to be enclosed with quotes yo avoid syntax errors, and of course "/C" is a invalid command when you try it into cmd 'cause /C is a cmd switch, not a DOS command. Example of quotes: CMD "/C "Del /Q "C:\Dir\\*""

Comment: ShellExecute as their name says it uses ShellExecute to start a file with the associated program, it's usefull for example to run text files with the default text editor instead notepad.exe or for .MSI installers, but not for CMD.exe or any other EXE files, do not activate shellexecute. PS: Forgive my English

Answer (score 4):

Don't use shell out (use the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) object) to do something you could do with native .Net objects.

```
DirectoryInfo tempDir = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Users\\WinUser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\abc\\");

foreach (FileInfo tempFile in tempDir.GetFiles())
{
    tempFile.Delete();
}
```

See:

- [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss.aspx)
- [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather do:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\WinUser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\abc", "*.tmp");

foreach (string filename in files)
    File.Delete(filename);
```

Because .Net has equivalent functionality

Also with the `SearchOption.AllDirectories` all sub-directory `"*.tmp"` files can be deleted also.